# 2 Instances of Tomcat and JBoss on the Same Hardware with Different IP’s

Tags: linux, tomcat, jboss

I’m trying to setup 2 separate instances of Tomcat and JBoss on the same physical server.  Both instances will use the same ports but will have different IP’s (IP#1, IP#2).  Right now I have the first instance of Tomcat and JBoss installed and they work fine.  When I grep the word localhost I see it being used in about a hundred locations within the Tomcat and JBoss internal files.  Since localhost is assigned to 127.0.0.1, and 127.0.0.1 is assigned to the first IP as loopback, do I need to replace “localhost” with the IP address in all of the Tomcat and JBoss files for each instance?

Answer (score 1):

I may be incorrect, but I do not believe you can have both systems running on the same machine  with the same port number regardless of their ip address. Since they run locally they run off of the host machines ports the ip addresses would resolve to the host server and not be able to distinguish what traffic on the same port needed to be rerouted unless you used apache to proxy the requests to tomcat or jboss.

[Use apache to redirect traffic to JBoss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357035/apache-jboss-use-port-80-at-the-same-time)

furthermore, how are getting the two systems to run at the same time. One should be complaining about the other having control over the port.